# Deezer Javascript SDK pause() method doesn't work on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, deezer

The Deezer Javascript SDK `DZ.player.pause()` method doesn't seem to work on iOS, even the pause button in Deezer's InApp Demo Application doesn't do anything. Is it going to be fixed soon?

In the meantime, is there any workaround to achieve the same thing? For instance, I tried starting to play an invalid album, but that had no effect.

Comment: When you say "the pause button in Deezer's InApp Demo Application doesn't do anything", you mean on the website or in your iOS application? I checked on the website, and no problem for me

Comment: I meant inside the iOS application, when you access it from your apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This bug is fixed in the application version that will be published in 3 weeks.