# Deezer Javascript SDK playAlbum autoplay flag ignored on Android

Tags: javascript, android, deezer

In my Deezer InApp, I am loading an album to the player with the `DZ.player.playAlbum` Javascript SDK call with the `autoplay` flag set to `false` like this: `DZ.player.playAlbum(10008268, false, 0, 0)`. On the desktop site and on iOS, it works as expected and doesn't start playing the track, but on Android, playback is started. Is this a bug in the Android version of the SDK?

Comment: If this flag doesn't work for you, did you try to do an immediate `DZ.player.pause`, after the `DZ.player.playAlbums` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following with the `player_play` event:

```
DZ.player.playAlbums(/*someID*/);
DZ.Event.subscribe('player_play', () => {
    DZ.player.pause();
}, true); //execute this once
```

Listen when the player started to play, then stop it immediately.

Comment: Great, it does work on Android! But I can't use it on iOS until the [pause method works on iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30762068/deezer-javascript-sdk-pause-method-doesnt-work-on-ios), so I may need OS detection or some other hack.